# High cabin pressure flights?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, health, accessibility

I've got dysfunction in my ears; this drastically slows the regulation of pressure behind my eardrums. The result of this is that the pressure changes while flying put excessive pressure on my eardrums; very painful, and risks bursting them (which luckily has not happened thus far). I've flown 6 times - all a320s (inc. a319), on short 2hr-ish continental flights. I'd like to fly transatlantic, but I'm worried about eardrum damage.

I understand that newer airliners like the B787 and A350 are composite and can operate at a higher cabin pressure, reducing the pressure differential on my eardrums. Does anyone know of any airlines or flights who explicitly operate at higher pressure? Does anyone have experience with this sort of situation, or help with how else to manage it?

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that aircraft type is not guaranteed, and even if you book a flight scheduled to be operated by, for example, a Boeing 787, the airline may switch it to another aircraft for any number of operational or commercial reasons. Given the amount of pain and risk you feel on shorter, possibly lower altitude flights, addressing this with a medical professional before flying sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Willeke "ask your family doctor" quite naturally follows. _No way_ I am going to give actual medical advice, we are not that kind of forum.

Comment: @chx You're right; my doctor has suggested nasal steroids, so as to give my tubes more "oomph" in shifting air. His general opinion however was that for short and infrequent flights, the side effects outweighed the benefits.

Comment: It’s worth noting that if the problem for you is the change in pressure rather than the low pressure (which is likely), then there will be no difference between a 2 hour flight and a 12-hour one: the only changes occur during take-off and landing (unless you happen to stumble on the extremely unlikely pressurisation incident).

Comment: @jcaron oh yes, my reasoning was that longer flights might take advantage of the greater distance to make a more shallow and gradual climb; perhaps not.

Comment: The goal is usually to climb to cruising altitude as quickly as possible, and stay there as long as possible. Very short flights will often not have the time to reach the highest altitudes, but beyond 2 hours it should be the same. Note that aircraft don’t stay at the exact same altitude during the whole cruise, but the variations at those levels are quite small compared to what happens during takeoff and landing.

Comment: Also, I don’t know what your medical condition is, but something many inexperienced flyers don’t know: you need to swallow as much as possible during the pressure change phases. With properly functioning Eustachian tubes this will open them and regulate the pressure in your inner ear. Gum or lollipops are your friends.

Comment: @jcaron good point, I could imagine someone sitting there in pain and ignorance, and they don't tell you this stuff in the safety briefing.  There are several other ways to do it also.  Yawning, drinking, etc.

Comment: I believe the steepness of the ascent/descent depends more on the airport than the length of the flight. To/from certain airports (e.g. London City, where I believe I could sense it on take-off), planes do a faster altitude change, presumably to reduce the noise heard on the ground.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, yawning is probably the most efficient, but it's sometimes a bit difficult to do that on demand and repeatedly. But now that you mentioned it I'm stuck with a repeated yawning episode... :-)

Comment: For your 2-hour flights, you can probably try to travel by bus or train, unless you live in an area where this is very dangerous (such as some parts of Africa) or your flight crosses bodies of water that have no ferries or fixed crossings.

Comment: You could try using a special type of earplugs called "earplanes". I haven't tried it myself, but it seems to have good reviews.

Comment: If we're sharing anti-pressure tips, I hold my nose while exhaling with closed mouth.

Comment: @jcaron unfortunately it's my Eustachian tubes that are the problem haha. Whether they're simply underdeveloped or weak and dilated it's unknown, but simply put they are able to move less air than they ought to.

Comment: @irfan Unfortunately yes, I've tried earplanes. No luck; I don't know if I didn't get a good seal, if they don't work in my situation, or if they're just not that functional - hard to tell.

Comment: Not a direct answer to this, but the ear doctor [who patched up my flight-ruptured eardrum](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22455/what-should-i-do-to-avoid-ear-pain-when-flying/152053#152053) recommended I always use nasal spray about 20 minutes before takeoff and landing.   Big part of the problem is apparently due to congested airways.

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple aircraft that can operate at a higher cabin pressure. The cabin pressure is typically measured in "equivalent altitude" and ironically lower altitudes correspond to higher pressure (and vice versa).

For those who prefer "real units": 0 ft = 100 kPa, 4000 ft = 87.5 kPa, 6000 ft = 81.2 kPa, 8000 ft = 75 kPa, where kPa is a "kilo Pascal" with Pascal being the official unit of pressure (1 newton per square meter).

Legal requirement is 8000 ft and all commercial planes can do that. There are three planes that can operate at "higher pressures", i.e. 6000 ft. These are A380, A350, B787.

That means they CAN operate are higher pressures, but they don't have to and the airline is not going to guarantee it. This being said, it's a frequently advertised benefit, it's recommended by the manufacturer and it doesn't add significant operating cost, so there is little reason for the airline not to use the feature.

I was on one of the very first Lufthansa flights with the A350. Lufthansa made a big deal out of it and asked us to fill out a horribly overwrought survey to track how we were feeling during the flight.

Keep in mind that the actual pressure depends  A LOT on your cruise altitude: while a clunky old Boeing 767 will can lower the pressure down to 8000 ft, it will only do so at a cruise altitude of 40,000 ft. If you are cruising at 30,000 ft the 767 operates at a pressure of about 4000 ft.

Your best bet is to go with a "modern" airplane (A380, A350, B787) and hope for the best. I also found that newer airplanes are quieter which makes IMO a big difference too. I highly recommend wearing noise cancelling headphones and ear buds. In my experience that reduces fatigue a lot more than fancy lighting or slightly low pressure and reduced fatigue makes it a lot easier to deal with ears popping and pressure problems.

Good luck

Comment: B777x (new models). -- the 777X is not in operation and won't be until 2025.

Comment: Thanks. Will fix (i got confused by the naming conventions)

Comment: "The cabin pressure is typically measured in "equivalent elevation" and ironically lower elevations correspond to higher pressure (and vice versa)."
Odd use of "ironically".

Comment: You might want to look into pressure relieving ear plugs.  They basically have a filter that slows down the pressure exchange.  https://www.amazon.com/Macks-Flightguard-Airplane-Pressure-Earplugs/dp/B01K9RHZ3S